# Finding an Error in matlab while doing homography via DLT

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, homography, dlt

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-9 and the size of the right side is 1-by-12.

I get this error when I start a loop for assigning and calculating values in MATLAB. Below is a screenshot of the function.

[image]

Comment: In the future, please provide actual code that can be runnable in MATLAB.  A screenshot does not help anyone in debugging your error.

Answer (score 0):

`A` needs to be declared as 12 x 12. You have it set as 12 x 9.

Comment: thank you ! sure i will take care of your feedback.